# Want to update table in MS Access to add column and populate based on other column

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement, sql-update, alter

I have a table (Fruit) in access that is in the form
Fruit, Cost 
and I want to update the table so that I will have 
Fruit, Cost, Cost bracket
and the cost bracket will be based on cost e.g Cost = .89 - Cost bracket='<1dollar', Cost=2 -Cost bracket ='1-5dollars' etc.

So far I have:

```
        Alter Table [Fruit]
        Add  [Cost Bracket] Varchar(50) 
       Update [Cost Bracket]
        Set [Cost Bracket] = Switch(Cost<1,'<1 dollar',Cost Between 1 and 
        5,'1-  5 dollars' etc...)
```

Comment: Why use code to alter table? Isn't this a one-time event? Do it manually in table design view. Then run an UPDATE action. But, saving calculated value is not really necessary. Can do this calculation when needed. However, `BETWEEN AND` probably won't work. `Switch(Cost<1,"<1 dollar", Cost<=5, "1-5 dollars", Cost<=…)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying the structure of your current table to include a cost bracket description* and then populating this additional field with fixed values dependent upon the value held by the `Cost` field, an alternative might be to construct a separate table containing the upper & lower bounds of the cost brackets and the corresponding descriptions.

For example, assuming that your **Fruit** table looks something along the lines of:

[image]

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| ID |   fruit   | cost  |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Apple     | £0.50 |
|  2 | Orange    | £0.80 |
|  3 | Pineapple | £3.00 |
|  4 | Grape     | £1.50 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

You might create a **Cost Brackets** table with the following structure:

[image]

And populate it with the following cost bracket data:

[image]

```
+----+--------+--------+-------------+
| ID | lbound | ubound | description |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | £0.00  | £1.00  | < £1        |
|  2 | £1.01  | £2.00  | < £2        |
|  3 | £2.01  | £5.00  | < £5        |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Then, you can link the two using a query such as:

```sql
select f.*, c.description
from fruit f left join cost_brackets c on (f.cost between c.lbound and c.ubound)
```

Yielding the following result for the above sample data:

[image]

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| ID |   fruit   | cost  | description |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | Apple     | £0.50 | < £1        |
|  2 | Orange    | £0.80 | < £1        |
|  3 | Pineapple | £3.00 | < £5        |
|  4 | Grape     | £1.50 | < £2        |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

This approach has the distinct advantage that, if you subsequently decide to change the ranges of your cost brackets and their associated descriptions, the change need only be made in **one place** and the values will cascade through all queries which reference the Cost Brackets table.

Whereas, with your current approach, any change to the cost brackets would involve:

- Changing the hard-coded cost brackets found within the `Switch` functions used in every query (and hope that you've covered them all).
- Update the values held by every table which contains the cost bracket description and hope that the value shown by a table has been suitably updated and reflects the current cost brackets.

---

<sub>**Which seems like it should be a one-time task and part of your database design, rather than an operation to be performed by code (unless perhaps you are generating the table on-the-fly?)*</sub>